# React-Redux API documentation symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, reactjs, redux

I'm reading the [react-redux documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) and I found this:

> [mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function)

I don't understand exactly what "**[ ]**" means, or what is the "**:**" symbol used for in this context. 
I remember that jQuery also uses this for it's API documentation. Example:

> .slideToggle([duration][,complete])

Is there any convention for writing/reading these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets indicate that a parameter is optional, colons indicate some kind of type declaration.

So, for `mapStateToProps`: it is an optional argument to `connect`.  It should always be declared with a first parameter which will be the Redux state tree, and *may* be declared to take a second parameter which will be the props given to the wrapper component.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what they meant by ": stateProps"?

Comment: A `mapState` function returns an object, and each key in the object becomes a prop to your component.  A `mapDispatch` function does the same thing.  _If_ you supply a `mergeProps` function, it will be called with the output of `mapState` and `mapDispatch` as separate parameters.  So, `stateProps` means "the output of `mapState`", ie, whatever data is inside that object.

Answer (score 3):

"[]" means not nesessary, but can be used.